# Fabric TextBox z-index not proper when document ready

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have 2 images on canvas set when page loads and adding a fabric Textbox after it.

Textbox is added but at the back of the images. but same textbox when I'm adding on click of the button its added on top of every object on canvas.

below is my code

```
fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = true;
fabric.Object.prototype.padding = 5;
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas',{preserveObjectStacking: false});
canvas.controlsAboveOverlay = true;
canvas.setHeight(600);
canvas.setWidth(424);

//Code for adding first image
var cnt=0;
var imgObj = new Image();
imgObj.src = "blank.png";
var imgmain=imgObj.onload = function () {
var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
image.set({
    id:'changeimg',
    angle: 0,
    height:100,
    width:100,
    align: 'mid', //added
    originX: 'center', //added
    originY: 'center', //added
});
canvas.centerObject(image);
if(cnt==0){
    canvas.add(image);
}
}

//Code for adding second image
var temp_path=$("#hdnTemplate").val();
var imgObj1 = new Image();
imgObj1.src = temp_path;        
var imgmain=imgObj1.onload = function () {
var image1 = new fabric.Image(imgObj1);
image1.set({
    id:'backgroundimg',
    angle: 0,
    width:canvas.getWidth(),
    height:canvas.getHeight(),
    evented:false,
    selectable:false,
    /*scaleX:1,
    scaleY:1,*/
});
 canvas.add(image1);
}

//Code for adding textbox
var text1=canvas.add(new fabric.Textbox('New Text', { 
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    fontFamily: 'comic sans ms',
    fill: '#FF0000',
    fontSize: 25
}));
```

The same code of adding textbox on canvas on button click adds the textbox above all layers

Comment: `onload` is an asynchronous method

Answer (score 0):

Image loading takes time and is asyncronous.

Your code is adding the textbox as first object and loading 2 images.

When loading is done, your code will add the images to the canvas.

If you can't control when images will finish loading, what you can do is to create 2 image object with empty images, and on the onload event use the 'setElement' or 'setSrc' to refresh your object